# Combining prototype and "class" inheritance in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

In my JavaScript application, I have several kinds of objects, including `Query`, `Document` and `Posting` . A Document contains a bunch of metadata about a document (title, abstract, etc.); a Posting represents some Document retrieved by some Query at some rank. The same Document may be retrieved by more than one Query, and thus may have more than one Posting associated with it.

The application has two relevant views: one that displays all Postings for a given Query, and one that displays all Documents. Since the user can interact with the two views in much the same way, I decided to use prototype inheritance by making a Document instance the prototype of one or more Posting instances. That way, the Posting inherits all of the metadata from the Document, and just adds its own Query reference and rank value. Works like a charm.

In addition to data (Query, rank) a posting carries some behavior as well. I wanted to factor out this behavior so that I don't have thousands of identical methods being created. In the case of Document, I simply moved all my functions to `Document.prototype`. But in the case of Postings, I cannot do that, because each Posting has a different prototype (its respective Document). While I could put some of the methods used by Posting into `Document.prototype` and get at them that way, some of the methods are polymorphic and need to be implemented differently for Document and Posting.

My question is this: if I am using prototype inheritance in Posting to carry *data*, can I somehow also factor out *behavior* so that I reuse the same method function instances for all my Posting instances instead of creating a new batch of methods every time I create a new Posting?

```
function Document(id, title) {
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
}

// Here prototype is used to factor out behavior
Document.prototype.document = function() { return this; }
Document.prototype.toString = function() { return 'Document [' + this.id + ']: "' + this.title + '"'; }


function Posting(query, rank) {
    this.query = query;
    this.rank = rank;

    // Can I move these two definitions out of the Posting instance to avoid
    // creating multiple copies of these functions as I construct 1000s of Postings?
    this.document = function() { return Object.getPrototypeOf(this); }
    this.toString = function() { return this.document().toString() + ' at rank ' + this.rank; }
}

function createPosting(query, document, rank) {
    // here prototype is used to share data
    Posting.prototype = document;
    var posting = new Posting(query, rank);
    return posting;
}
```

**UPDATE**

I made a mistake in the code example above: the correct way to do inheritance (as pointed out in comments below) is to set the prototype first: `Posting.prototype = document;` I think the rest of my question is still valid :-)

Comment: `posting.prototype = Document;` What's the point of this? `posting` is an object, the `prototype` property does not have any specific meaning. You are not setting up inheritance this way. Only the `prototype` property of **functions** is special. Generally I have to say that making a Posting instance inherit from a specific Document instance does not sound like a proper use of inheritance. Maybe you are more looking for composition? I.e. a Posting *has a* Document, instead of a Posting *is a* Document.

Comment: If this is in a browser, I would choose a different name since `Document` already has meaning.

Comment: @CrazyTrain Do you mean `document` (lowercase `D`) or do you just mean in general? Like that the idea of a "document" has a meaning in browsers? I wasn't sure if there was some magical `Document` object I didn't know about :)

Comment: Overall I find your setup too confusing to provide an alternative solution. Maybe you can make the relation between Posting and Document clearer?

Comment: A `Document` instance `document` stores some data; one or more `Posting` instances inherit the *data* from each `Document` and add some more data to it. I thought it was pretty clear :-(

Comment: @FelixKling regarding your first comment, the code says `posting.prototype = document`. The case distinction is important. A `posting` inherits from a specific `document`, not from the "class" `Document`.

Comment: @GeneGolovchinsky that doesn't make sense, you can't inherit from instances. Well, you can in JavaScript (because it's awesome like that) but it's confusing to anyone reading or using your code.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen I believe the whole point of prototype inheritance is to inherit from instances!

Comment: I believe the whole point of prototype inheritance is to get people to use JavaScript _"because it has classes and inheritance"_. JavaScript was released when Java and OOP were buzzing.

Comment: _"I wanted to factor out this behavior so that I don't have thousands of identical methods being created"_ - This makes no sense. When you create an object from a prototype a million times, you get a million pointers, not a million methods.

Comment: @Ian: The `Document` is a constructor function in browsers. `document instanceof Document; // true`

Comment: @CrazyTrain Where the hell have I been? And why didn't I just test? I mean, where does `document` come from? Has to come from somewhere! That was dumb, haha thanks for explaining

Comment: @Gene: Yes, I get that, but as I said, only *functions* have a special `prototype` property. If you assign a `prototype` property to an object, it's just an arbitrary property that has the name "prototype". No inheritance is established.

Comment: I am not sure you're right: this http://jsfiddle.net/gene/wgK4p/ jsfiddle illustrates that the two *bar* functions are not the same

Comment: Do not use `new` and see http://jsfiddle.net/PEjEr/

Comment: @JonasG.Drange If a and b have different state, this doesn't seem to work. See http://jsfiddle.net/gene/GEHZy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you save the functions outside the constructor of Posting.

```
function Document(id, title) {
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
}

// Here prototype is used to factor out behavior
Document.prototype.document = function() { return this; }
Document.prototype.toString = function() { return 'Document [' + this.id + ']: "' + this.title + '"'; }

function PostingToString()
{
  return this.document().toString() + ' at rank ' + this.rank;
}
function PostingDocument ()
{
    return Object.getPrototypeOf(this);
}
function Posting(query, rank) {
    this.query = query;
    this.rank = rank;

    this.document = PostingDocument; 
    this.toString = PostingToString;
}


function createPosting(query, document, rank) {
    var posting = new Posting(query, rank);
    // here prototype is used to share data
    posting.prototype = document;
    return posting;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about this compromise. One question: will `PostingDocument` and `PostingToString` functions be bound to the right object (so that `this` refers to the specific instance)?

Comment: There is a limitation with this approach: to guarantee that `PostingDocument` and `PostingToString` are called with the right `this` value, `bind()` needs to be called on them. But `bind()` makes a copy of the function on which it's called, defeating the savings from having to specify the code once. This problem occurs when these functions are called by knockoutjs events.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to test memory usage of Javascript in browsers... As pointed out in a comment by Gene .bind() makes a copy of the function, so the solution of Parthik Gosar doesn't save any memory. Furthermore it still has references to functions that are not really handled as references in most browsers. So even without the bind() function this will consume a lot of memory.

This approach should save a lot of memory...

```
var staticFcts = {
    'document': {
        'document': function() { return this; },
        'posting': function() { return Object.getPrototypeOf(this); }
    },
    'toString': {
        'document': function() { return 'Document [' + this.id + ']: "' + this.title + '"'; },
        'posting': function() { return this.document().toString() + ' at rank ' + this.rank; }
    }   
};

var myOwnProxy = function(method) {  
    var c = staticFcts[method][this.typeOf].bind(this);
    return c();
}



function Document(id, title) {
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
}

Document.prototype.document = function() { var p = myOwnProxy.bind(this,'document');     return p.call(); };
Document.prototype.toString = function() { var p =     myOwnProxy.bind(this,'toString');return p.call(); }; 
Document.prototype.typeOf = 'document'; // default type is 'document', this is necessary
// because there is no way in Javascript to determine the class name.
// Unfortunantely "Proxy" (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)  is not widely supported either.

function Posting(query, rank) {
    this.query = query;
    this.rank = rank;
}

function createPosting(query, document, rank) {
    Posting.prototype = document;
    var posting = new Posting(query, rank);
    posting.typeOf = 'posting'; //overwrite type

    return posting;
}


var docs = [];
var postings= [];

var now = new Date().getTime();

// memory and performance test
for($i=0;$i<100000;$i++) {
 var d = new Document(1,'document1');
 var p = createPosting('query1', d, 1);
    docs.push(d);
    postings.push(p);
}
console.log('needed time', ((new Date().getTime())-now)/1000 + ' sec');

function roughSizeOfObject( object ) {

    var objectList = [];
    var stack = [ object ];
    var bytes = 0;

    while ( stack.length ) {
        var value = stack.pop();

        if ( typeof value === 'boolean' ) {
            bytes += 4;
        }
        else if ( typeof value === 'string' ) {
            bytes += value.length * 2;
        }
        else if ( typeof value === 'number' ) {
            bytes += 8;
        }
        else if
        (
                typeof value === 'object'
            && objectList.indexOf( value ) === -1
        )
        {
            objectList.push( value );

            for( i in value ) {
                stack.push( value[ i ] );
        }
        }
    }
    return bytes;
}   

console.log('memory usage: ', roughSizeOfObject(docs) + roughSizeOfObject(postings));
```

Simon

Comment: How does `roughSizeOfObject()` account for member functions?

Comment: It's just a guess of the real size..  in javascript everything is an object, member functions are treated as objects too. 
But as mentioned before, it's not really possible to measure the right memory usage. What you could do, is to use the toString method to get the javascript code of the method and add this as memory size.

e.g.: arguments.callee.toString().length or through the .prototype.toString()..but the toString method is overwritten in this case, so this will not work as expected!